# How many people have 15 prestige in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Does anyone have a link to a site that keeps track of how many people have 15 prestige in BO?

Comment: This question is pretty localized (the number will constantly be changing).

Comment: I edited to make it more clear that a web resource that keeps track of this number would be an acceptable answer. Simply answering with the current number would be entirely localized.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot view the statistics of how many people have the 15th Prestige on the Internet, even in-game but you can see how many people have prestiged on the game console network by seeing the toolbar that shows mini-stats that says `X people have prestiged X times`. So that is the closest you can see.